# How to pass type parameters up a class hierachy

Tags: java

I thought I could pass a type parameter up a hierarchy like this

```
public class A extends B<Dog>{

}

public class B<Animal extends Organism> extends C<Animal>{

}
```

but the types in class C are of type Organism not of type Dog, altough the types in class B are in fact of type Dog.

Is there a way to pass the type parameter up the class hierarchy?

**edit**

Above example makes it difficult to distinguish between types and type parameters as mentioned; thanks for pointing that out:

```
public class A extends B<Dog>{

}

public class B<T extends Organism> extends C<T>{

}
```

The erased types in class C are of type Organism during run-time, not of type Dog, but the erased types in class B are of type dog. I want to the erased types in class C to also be of type Dog. Does that make sense?

Comment: What you're doing looks fine. Please elaborate on why you think it's not working.

Comment: As an aside: It is common to use a single uppercase letter for generic types to distinguish them from actual types. In your class `B`, it is unclear whether `Animal` is an actual type or a generic (I suspect the latter).

Comment: Yeah, the compiler will see `Animal` as a type parameter here, which can get confusing when you see it in the code.  Best not to use type parameters that look like they might be class names.  (Mind you, given that the class names are `A`, `B` and `C`, maybe this isn't an issue).

Comment: @shmosel i added an edit for clarity, should what I'm trying to do still work?

Comment: No. But why do you care about the erased type?

Comment: @shmosel My language is probably wrong; basically, i just want the types in class C to be type Dog, not type Organism when the types are erased.

Comment: It will be of type `Dog` at compile time, but not at runtime, when the types are erased. Perhaps it will help to explain what you're really trying to accomplish; this sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the erased types in class C are of type Organism during run-time".  The whole point of erased types is ... they've been erased.

Comment: @shmosel okay, thanks, I'll present the actual problem. In the mean time, I am curious, if I declare a list `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList();` the the compile type is erased over with `Object` right, but one can only add type `Integer` to the list?

Comment: It's erased to `Object` regardless. You're confusing erasure with raw types.